Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first
I'm receiving this weird error even though I'm not using firebase in my react-native project.
Does anyone knows how to fix this nightmarish issue? I've been stuck into this for a week now.
Error
Gradle
I saw similar issues, from StackOverflow to Github, tried them all, but none of them seem to solve my issue.

Share the packages the application is using.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
